# Control orientation Android when option "Auto-rotate screen" is disable in setting?

Tags: android, android-orientation

As you can see Youtube app for Android that can rotate screen from portrait to landscape even when option "Auto-rotate screen" is disable in setting. How can i do same it? Thank all guys!

Answer (score 3):

Use - `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR` if you want to rotate screen irrespective of user's choice else use `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER`. This will only rotate screen if its turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Use setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR), it will disregard the auto rotate option and just rotate whenever your device is rotated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

//This is the default value
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);

public static void setAutoOrientationEnabled(ContentResolver resolver, boolean enabled)
{

    Settings.System.putInt(resolver, Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, enabled ? 1 : 0);

}
```

Comment: if Auto-rotate screen" was disabled in setting, I don't  know when my phone rotate. Are you understand my objective?

Comment: Thank Helios-Ignite, i can set Orientation of Android device when use your method "setAutoOrientationEnabled" above. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

As it's shown here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_overview.html you can register your own sensor (`TYPE_ACCELEROMETER` in this case) and then listen on it's events.

When you calculate that phone orientation has been changed you should programmatically change layout orientation then.

Comment: [link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSensor/article.html) and  [link](http://www.slideshare.net/info_zybotech/android-accelerometer-sensor-tutorial) - here are the best tutorials in this topic which I know.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in onCreate of that activity you want to be able to rotate the screen:

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED);

It won't affect other activities or the whole device settings.

I have tried that. It works.